# Android Styling Design

Tags: android, android-layout

I have to create below style for my Android Page is it possible to make through it styling 
using (Shape etc)

> [image: [1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/5edz4.png][1]]

```
 if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){

        ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll_vw);
        sv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.login_image_portrait);
    }
    else{
        ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll_vw);
        sv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.login_image_landscape);

    }
```

> Currently I have taken it as Image and run time I look for orientation and set the drawable . I tried it a lot through XML and using custom view but couldn't get it (In this I have to put the Edit Box and Buttons at specific position after using custom view only layout i can use was frame that didnt give me the control over the widgets position)

Comment: @SandipArmalPatil First of all I am new in Android well as Stack Over flow also and If havnt put the code that didnt mean I didnt put effort yes I agree I should put the code

Comment: @SandipArmalPatil please remove  the minus vote .. :(

Comment: it's good to put the code... without your code no one understand what problem you face...

Comment: @SandipArmalPatil now can u help me